# "Редкие породы мрамора пронизаны рисунком" - так?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Драгоценные, редкие породы мрамора пронизаны естественным прихотливым
>   рисунком.

Почему-то меня смущает глагол "пронизать"; рисунок проходит насквозь?

Comment: Да, именно так — насквозь.

Comment: Гриззличек! Так и ответь. Мол, предложение совершенно верно построено и неча к ему чиплятися.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что в части "пронизывания мрамора рисунком" предложение построено верно. В качестве примера приведу одну из цитат, найденных в Google.books:

> С течением времени каменный рисунок не выцветает, так как не наносится
>   на лицевую поверхность, а пронизывает плитку по всей толщине.

Все эти жилки, линии, расцветки действительно имеют объёмный характер (при желании этот объёмный рисунок можно смоделировать на компьютере, например).